# Using ifelse or case_when on a data frame in R

Tags: r, if-statement, case, na

I am sure the solution to my problem is simple but I am new to coding and cannot seem to find the answer online. I am working on a dataset that is made up of qualitative data that was collected and coded. The dataset includes variables named code 1, code 2, code 3, code 4 and each respondent can have multiple codes and they all have at least one code. I am trying to add a variable that will reflect the number of codes given to a participant.
So, participants data looks something like this with the numerical values being codes that we assign given their response:

```
ID Code1 Code2 Code3 Code4
1.  5      NA    NA    NA 
2.  7       6    4     NA
3.  5      12    NA    NA
```

The variable I want to include would be the one named count and would look like this:

```
ID Code1 Code2 Code3 Code4 Count
1.  5      NA    NA    NA   1
2.  7       6    4     NA   3
3.  5      12    NA    NA   2
```

The first participant would have the number 1 under Count because they only received one code, participant 2 would have a number three under count because they have three codes, and participant 3 would have 2 codes under count because they were only assigned two codes.

Anyway, I have tried using the ifelse function using NA since that signals that fewer codes were assigned but when I try to use it I cannot assign more than 2 outcomes, that is my count variable cannot be more than two different numbers and these can go up to 4. I have also tried using case_when but get an error message saying Error: Case 7 (`!is.na(Code1) ~ 1`) must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector.

Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
df$count = ifelse(is.na(df$Code2),1,2)

df$count = ifelse(is.na(Klara$Code3),2,3)

df$count = ifelse(is.na(Klara$Code4),3,4)
```

I have also tried:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(count = case_when(!is.na(Code1) ~ 1, 
                                 !is.na(Code2) ~ 2, 
                                 !is.na(Code3) ~ 3,
                                 !is.na(Code4) ~ 4,
                                xor(Code1,Code2)))
```

So, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong and how I can get the count variable I need to work. Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dplyr` approach using `rowSums` and `across`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

dat <- dat |>
  mutate(count = rowSums(
    across(starts_with("Code"), ~ !is.na(.x))
  ))
dat
#>   ID Code1 Code2 Code3 Code4 count
#> 1  1     5    NA    NA    NA     1
#> 2  2     7     6     4    NA     3
#> 3  3     5    12    NA    NA     2
```

Or using base R:

```
dat$count <- rowSums(
  !is.na(dat[grep("^Code", names(dat), value = TRUE)])
)
dat
#>   ID Code1 Code2 Code3 Code4 count
#> 1  1     5    NA    NA    NA     1
#> 2  2     7     6     4    NA     3
#> 3  3     5    12    NA    NA     2
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3), Code1 = c(5L, 7L, 5L), Code2 = c(
  NA,
  6L, 12L
), Code3 = c(NA, 4L, NA), Code4 = c(NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -3L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hoping this will also be helpful
Recreating the data set as above

```
a = c(1, 5, NA, NA, NA)
b = c(2, 7, 6,  4,  NA)
c = c(3, 5, 12, NA, NA)

df <- cbind(a,b,c) %>%
t() %>% 
data.frame() %>% 
setNames(c('id', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4'))
```

#dplyr snippet

```
df  |> 
na_replace(0)|> 
pivot_longer( code1:code4, names_to = "tag", values_to="count") |> 
group_by(id) |> 
summarise_all(~sum(. != 0)) |> 
select(id, count) |> left_join(df, by =c("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

Recreating data (using tidyverse) - you can ignore this

```
a = c(1, 5, NA, NA, NA)
b = c(2, 7, 6,  4,  NA)
c = c(3, 5, 12, NA, NA)

df <- cbind(a,b,c) %>%
  t() %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(c('id', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4'))
```

Solutions:

```
#a
df$count <- rowSums(!is.na(df) & !colnames(df)=='id')

#b
df$count <- apply(df, 1, \(x) sum(!is.na(x) & !colnames(df)=='id'))

  id code1 code2 code3 code4 count
a  1     5    NA    NA    NA     1
b  2     7     6     4    NA     3
c  3     5    12    NA    NA     2
```